# Where can I download the newest Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration.dll?

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

It's needed, but it's not obvious from the Castle homepage where this file sits. I am looking for a binary release, not source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HornGet is a good option:

http://hornget.net/packages/ioc/castle.facilities.activerecordintegration/castle.facilities.activerecordintegration-trunk

Castle's TeamCity build server is another option for getting binaries:

http://builds.castleproject.org/

http://builds.castleproject.org/repository/download/bt87/5399:id/Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration-.NETFramework-v3.5-49.zip

Answer (score 3):

try downloading the binaries directly from [HornGet](http://hornget.net/packages/ioc/). It is the latest compiled version from the trunk.

Comment: That's your best option. Currently the project has no leader, so it's been neglected a bit :|

Comment: The HornGet location for that project is saying "download unavailable" for me right now, so I also provided the TeamCity location in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a binary release anywhere, I am downloading the source code [from the git repository](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.ActiveRecordIntegration) and compiling it.